# mbed: Triggering interrupt at reception of an UDP broadcast message

Tags: udp, interrupt, stm32, ethernet, mbed

I'm trying to trigger an interrupt function each time I receive a broadcast message on a given port of an STM32 board (Nucleo f429zi). The communication protocol I use is UDP and the mbed library is `UDPSocket` which inherits from `Socket`.

Does anyone have an idea how to achieve it?

**Edit:**

Thanks to PeterJ's comment I found an interesting (but deprecated) member function of the class `Socket` which is called `attach()`. This method registers a callback on state change of the socket (recv/send/accept).

Since I have an incoming broadcast on the socket, there is no state change in my case (only receiving data, never sending). Is there a way I could use this `attach()` method to detect every message received?

```
// Open Ethernet connection
EthernetInterface eth;                          
eth.connect();

// Create an UDP socket for listening to the broadcast
UDPSocket broadcastSocket;
broadcastSocket.open(&eth);
broadcastSocket.bind(BROADCAST_PORT);

// Function to call when a broadcast message is received
broadcastSocket.attach(&onUDPSocketEvent);

void onUDPSocketEvent(){
    printf("UDP event detected\n");     
}
```

Comment: you will need to find the callback function name (or callback mechanism) in your library. There is nothing like "UDP interrupt" as STM32 uC do not have hardware IP stack built in.

Comment: Thank you @PeterJ, your comment helped me to go a little bit further. I just edited the question.

Comment: Look inside the library source code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`attach` has been replaced by [sigio](https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbed-os/blob/master/features/netsocket/Socket.h#L173), but I don't think it's going to do what you want. A nice way would be to spin up a new thread, and use this thread to handle the socket.

```
void onUDPSocketEvent(void* buffer, size_t size) {
    printf("UDP event detected\n");     
}

void udp_main() {
    // Open Ethernet connection
    EthernetInterface eth;                          
    eth.connect();

    // Create an UDP socket for listening to the broadcast
    UDPSocket broadcastSocket;
    broadcastSocket.open(&eth);
    broadcastSocket.bind(BROADCAST_PORT);

    void* recvBuffer = malloc(1024);

    while (1) {
        // this blocks until next packet comes in
        nsapi_size_or_error_t size = broadcastSocket.recvfrom(NULL, recvBuffer, 1024);
        if (size < 0) {
            printf("recvfrom failed with error code %d\n", size);
        }
        onUDPSocketEvent(recvBuffer, size);
    }
}

int main() {
    Thread t; // can pass in the stack size here if you run out of memory
    t.start(&udp_main);

    while (1) {
        wait(osWaitForever);
    }
}
```

(note that the callback function does not run in an ISR - so not in an interrupt context - but I assume you don't actually want that).

**Edit:** I have created [mbed-udp-ping-pong](https://github.com/janjongboom/mbed-udp-ping-pong) which shows how to listen for UDP messages on a separate thread.